# Req.Body POST Data Not Showing Up After Appending Form Fields

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Haven't been able to solve this problem at all, but long story short I have a button where the user is able to add a question and answer pair one at a time once he clicks on an "Add Question". This works by the append feature to a div. However the POST data doesn't show up in req.body at all once you submit. I have verified that the appended fields are within the form control and that each of those fields have a different id. I checked and re-checked a few posts online with users reporting the same problem to no avail.

The Add Question button is of type "button" while the save button is of type "submit".

Not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?...

Comment: look into body-parser the express middleware

Comment: yes im using body-parser already

Comment: ok then show us some code.

Comment: Added it in my edit

Comment: @mysticarcher I don't see any code added?  Maybe you aren't using the correct `app.use` to include the middleware - but that's pure speculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely don't have a body parser in place for this.  It *still* catches me out after 5 years of Node/Express dev that Express doesn't provide a parser for this out of the box - but it doesn't.

The most commonly used parser is [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), but this not able to support multipart data.

There are many body parsers that will support multipart data, several of which are actually mentioned on the `body-parser` NPM Readme.  Personally, I favour `formidable` but many are good.  `express-formidable` is an express implentation of this.

### Basic usage of [`express-formidable`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable#readme)

`$ npm install -S express-formidable`

```
const formidable = require('express-formidable')
app.use(formidable())
```

*NB: If you aren't using express, then you can use the [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable#readme) NPM for Node `http.Server` instances too.*

Comment: I'm already using body-parser but are you stating that it would be better to use formidable instead? To add, body-parser works just fine if I load a form with the fields already there, but if I dynamically add the fields when the user clicks the button and appends the new fields, the POST data of those new fields do not show up. The fields which already loaded onto the page do pass the POST data just fine.

Comment: As above, we're gonna need a code example to see what's what.

Comment: formidable worked great and it did get the post data after appending the fields, thanks!

Comment: The likely scenario is that you were processing multipart data then.